# How can I improve my collision detection's performance?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, performance, sfml

I'm new to programming and want to speed up the collision detection in my C++ 2D platformer game engine.

Currently, only the player's collision detection works: Every frame, the player's update function iterates through every level tile (which is pretty many) and checks if the player hitbox collides with it.

I may be way off on this, but this seems like a really chunky way of doing it. Is this bad practice? If the level gets large enough, is iterating through this list going to take forever like it seems it should?

My second question builds off of that: If I start adding for example enemies into the engine and give them a similar method for collision detection, can I expect performance drops? I'd like some insight from more experienced people on a better way of setting this up. I would just imagine that having ~20 enemies on the screen all iterating through all possible objects for collision with a list could get slow fast.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Preliminary warning**: *Optimisation* is a dangerous [cast-from-life](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CastFromLifespan)-type magic. You should always [optimise as late as possible](http://homepage.cs.uri.edu/~thenry/resources/unix_art/ch01s06.html), because machine time is cheap. Obfuscate your code for performance only when you know you need to. Many small games manage just fine with the simple method you've described.

---

That said, here's the news:

**The bad news** is that you're right: Giving larger inputs to any algorithm will eventually slow it down. Bigger problems are harder—that's a physical certainty.

**The good news** is that different algorithms slow down at different rates. The rate at which an algorithm slows down with respect to the input size is called its [computational complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_complexity).

I'll first explain computational complexity theory (what efficiency is) then some techniques to speed up your specific problem.

## A *slow* dumb algorithm

Let's start by making a slow algorithm, in a way no sane person would do it, because it's easier than making a fast one and better illustrates  *how to measure* an algorithm's efficiency.

The way you're doing it, *iterating through a list* to find whether any tile collides with your player has *[linear complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_time#Linear_time)* (often written as *O(n)-complexity* or *order-n-complexity*). This means that if you double the size of the input (how many tiles you have), that also doubles the time the algorithm takes to run.

Iterating over a...

...1-element list: `1`

...2-element list: `1 2`

...3-element list: `1 2 3`

...4-element list: `1 2 3 4`

...5-element list: `1 2 3 4 5`

...6-element list: `1 2 3 4 5 6`

...7-element list: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`

Iterating over a large list of `n` elements this way has complexity `O(n)`.

Some algorithms slow down even more easily: For example, imagine if every time you wanted to access one of the tiles in your list, you had to start over and iterate to that tile all over again from the start of the list. (No sane programmer would actually do this, but hey, it's a *possible* algorithm.)

Iterating over a whole list of different lengths would cause reads something like this:

Dumb-iterating over a...

...1-element list: `1`

...2-element list: `1 1 2`

...3-element list: `1 1 2 1 2 3`

...4-element list: `1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4`

...5-element list: `1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5`

...6-element list: `1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 6`

...7-element list: `1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 7`

That blew up pretty fast in comparison. Given a list of `n` elements, this algorithm takes `0.5 * n * (n + 1)` time. In computing, we often shorten this by calling it `O(n ^ 2)`, because the n-squared term [dominates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) as the list grows.

I'm sure we could come up with an *even dumber* way of iterating over a list with an [exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time) or even [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) complexity. Let's not do that. Instead, let's go to the other extreme.

## A *fast* dumb algorithm

Can we find the collision response of a player character with a large number of static walls in **constant time**? This is the fastest possible time complexity: It would mean taking the same amount of time regardless of the input size.

**Yes!** We could precompute and store *every possible position* that your player character could *possibly* be standing at and the appropriate precalculated collision response, in memory.

Assuming your game world is 2000 by 1000 pixels large and that your player and walls are positioned at integer coordinates, then you'd have to store a

```
struct CollisionResult {
    int collisionResponseX;
    int collisionResponseY;
}
```

for every possible position your player could be in (`struct CollisionResult[2000][1000] collisionResponseCache`) and you'd have a complete and immediately queryable cache of what collision to expect when a player is in any position.

This is a constant time algorithm: Indexing into an array (something like `collisionResponseCache[player->posX][player->posY]`) is just as fast for every possible input—mere milliseconds.

We've traded [memory space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_space) and flexibility to gain time complexity.

How much memory space? Assuming your machine has 4-byte integers, that big array would take up 2000 * 1000 * 2 * 4 = 16000000 bytes of space—that's 16MB. That's quite a lot of memory and it increases linearly with the size of your game world, though it's not too bad for a modern PC with gigabytes of RAM!

How much flexibility? This constant-time method assumes all of the things you want to test for collisions against are present and static (and hence precomputable). This is often limiting, as it prohibits moving enemies, collectibles, breakable walls and such.

## Spatial subdivision; worlds between

A better algorithm would allow more flexibility (changing inputs) but still be faster than linear time. How might we do that?

Consider a two-dimensional game world with some game entities in it.

[image: simple 2D world with square entities]

We could easily double the collision detection algorithm's efficiency by keeping two lists of objects instead of just one: A list for objects on the left half of the level and another for the right half:

[image: game world divided into 2 buckets]

Whenever an object crosses the boundary, we'd move it to the other list. This way, we only need to check for collisions against the objects in the list corresponding to the side of the stage the player is on.

We can take this further by introducing two more lists and splitting the level in four instead.

[image: game world divided into 4 buckets]

Or into twelfths. Hundredths? We can parametrise this as we like, to control how much flexibility and memory we want to trade for speed. Making each list represent a 1×1 area (a single pixel) makes this essentially degenerate to the "store absolutely everything"-approach above.

[image: many different grid sizes]

This is the gist of a spatial subdivision technique called [spatial hashing](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/spatial-hashing-r2697). The details are a little more complex, as you have to account for entities' sizes (they might be in many cells at once). C++ implementation details are the domain of [another question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56590/c-how-to-implement-a-spatial-hash-for-a-2d-game).

A *[quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree)* works in a similar manner, but it subdivides cells only as needed:

[image: a sample quadtree]

<sup>Many thanks to [David Eppstein](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:David_Eppstein) of [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Point_quadtree.svg)! The image page includes Python source code!</sup>

If your game objects are relatively sparse, quadtrees [may be significantly faster than a spatial hash](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69776/when-is-a-quadtree-preferable-over-spatial-hashing), so they're also worth investigating. Again, implementations and guides exist that I won't replicate here, but this is the gist of it.

Comment: Your answer is better than mine. :)

Comment: Fantastic all around, including a good introduction to the most fundamental optimization here.  There are things I'd have said differently, but to my mind this is the archetype of a good answer.

Comment: Thanks guys, it means a lot to me! :) @Steven If you have an alternative learning path, consider posting it as another answer (or editing it in if it fits well). A different viewpoint might be really useful for someone else looking to learn this.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Well thought out, well written, and has diagrams to boot. Have you considered writing an article on this?

Comment: @IanYoung Thank you! :) What sort of article do you mean?

Comment: @Anko A tutorial, or a blog post that could be posted on a game dev site for educational purposes.

Comment: @IanYoung I think I know what you mean. Full creative control of the page would help in explaining things even better. I'm a big fan of [Amit Patel's site](https://www.redblobgames.com/) for example, and would love to do something similar, with mixed text/interactive/video content. So far, I've stuck to Gamedev SE because it already has a community, and its plain text + pictures have been enough for most explanations. That said, I have some ideas for educational posts that wouldn't fit Gamedev SE's format… I'll try to make them happen in the future!

Comment: In the grid example you suggested. If it's a tile based game as it seems implied. I'd recommend doing a large block of 64 bit long values. Each long would store a 8x8 grid chunk in bits so every bit state could tell you if it's active or not. Could be useful for checking distance collision as well as you could check any of the 64 coordinates at once. Although you'd need to support a value for each diagonal and straight check with offsets. But it'd be pretty cool. So your 2000x1000 grid example would be 250KB then.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a QuadTree: See [(here)](http://www.kyleschouviller.com/wsuxna/quadtree-source-included/) and [(here)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

It allows an O(n^2) naive algorithm (iterating every object over every other object) to drop to an O(n) algorithm (only the objects in the same cell or objects contained in visible cells via a selection area (usually the camera's visible area).